# C - While loop before variables not compiling

Tags: c, variables, loops, while-loop, declaration

I'm trying to make a loop in the main method in C, and it's not compiling.

Here's the code:

```
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10) 
    {
        i++;
    }
    int x;
    int a;
    int b;
    int sum;
    sum = a + b;
```

It doesn't compile because this error:

```
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
```

This error appears in all the variables that are declared after the loop.

But, if I write the loop after these variable declaration, it works just fine.

So why can't I write a loop before variable declaration?

Comment: That was one of the changes introduced in C in about 1999. You seem to be using an implementation that targets C as defined prior to that.

Comment: Which compiler? (Visual Studio???)

Comment: Error message appearing in all variables: Error 3 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

Comment: It compiles with gcc - with lots of warnings of course.

Comment: @uraf: it doesn't if you ask nicely ... `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic-errors ...`

Comment: This error messages appears with all variables declared after the while loop. The IDE is Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express, and I chose the option "Compile with C only" in the properties.

Comment: @pmg, yeah I know. :)

Comment: @Himanshu the code is not valid in pre-C99

Comment: @Himanshu : Online compiler may be using using C99

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C89 all variables should be declared at the top of a code block i.e. directly after a `{`, they don't have to be declared at the top of a function. In C99 and later they can be declared anywhere. If you have a section of code in your function that needs to use a set of variables that the rest of the function doesn't you can wrap this section in a block `{...`}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical response of an outdated Microsoft Visual C compiler which does not support the latest C standard. Seems they've got stuck in time.

Just move the variables before the loop and all should be fine.